# Show that the local feature size is Lipschitz continuous

Tags: computational-geometry, euclidean-distance

In class we defined "local features size" $\rho$ as follows:

> Let $C$ be a smooth closed curve in the plane, and let $x$ be a
> point of $C$. The local feature size $\rho(x)$ of $x$ is the shortest distance from
> $x$ to the medial axis of $C$. (The medial axis $M(C)$ of a closed smooth
> curve $C$ is the locus of the centers of disks that touch $C$ at two or
> more distinct points.)

Furthermore in class it was said that it "trivially" holds that $\rho(x) \le \rho(y) + d(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in C$, where $d$ is the Euclidean Metric. However, I do not see why.

I strongly suspect that we have to use the triangle inequality here, but I do not see how.

My attempts so far look as follows: Let $\rho(x) = d(x,c_1)$ for some $c_1 \in M(C)$ and $\rho(y) = d(y,c_2)$ for some $c_2 \in M(C)$. Then we have

$$\rho(x) - \rho(y) = d(x,c_1)-d(y,c_2) \le d(x,c_1)+d(y,c_2) \le d(x,c_1)+d(y,c_1).$$

(The last inequality is due to the definition of $\rho$ as the *shortest distance*. This is close to what we want, but I can not go further from here.

Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: You are almost correct. $\rho(x) \le d(x, c_2) \le d(x, y) + d(y, c_2) = d(x, y) + \rho(y)$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks a lot for your help.